# How to change Ivy home in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-idea-2016

Changing the *Ivy* home directory for the command line version of *sbt* is quite simple. You just have to add the option `-Dsbt.ivy.home=<new ivy home dir>` to `$SBT_HOME/conf/sbtconf.txt`.

I want to do the same with the Scala extension of IntelliJ IDEA (I am running out of disk space on my C drive). Therefore, I modified the SBT settings in the following way: *File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment -> BuildTools -> SBT*. Under *VM parameters* I added the entry `-Dsbt.ivy.home=<new ivy home dir>`. This should have the same effect as in the command line tool.

When I create a new *sbt* based Scala project (and adding a Scala object that prints out a message), everything seems to work nicely. I can build and run the program. But after performing changes on the source code and making the project (*Build -> Make Project*) two or three times, I observe the following error:

```
Error:scalac: Error: assertion failed: 
  Precisely this override requires its invoker to hand out a non-null AbstractFile.
     while compiling: D:\Temp\scala\scalatest3\src\main\scala\Main.scala
        during phase: jvm
     library version: version 2.12.0
    compiler version: version 2.12.0
  reconstructed args: -nobootcp -javabootclasspath ; -classpath C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\temp\scala\scalatest3\target\scala-2.12\classes;D:\Bin\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-library\jars\scala-library-2.12.0.jar
  last tree to typer: TypeTree(class ListBuffer)
       tree position: line 4 of D:\Temp\scala\scalatest3\src\main\scala\Main.scala
            tree tpe: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[() => Unit]
              symbol: final class ListBuffer in package mutable
   symbol definition: final class ListBuffer extends AbstractBuffer with Buffer with GenericTraversableTemplate with BufferLike with ReusableBuilder with SeqForwarder with Serializable (a ClassSymbol)
      symbol package: scala.collection.mutable
       symbol owners: class ListBuffer
           call site: constructor Main$delayedInit$body in class Main$delayedInit$body in package <empty>
== Source file context for tree position ==
     1   * Created by P20058 on 14.11.2016.
     2   */
     3 object Main extends App {
     4   println("Hello scalatest")
     5 
     6 }
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
  Precisely this override requires its invoker to hand out a non-null AbstractFile.
     while compiling: D:\Temp\scala\scalatest3\src\main\scala\Main.scala
        during phase: jvm
     library version: version 2.12.0
    compiler version: version 2.12.0
  reconstructed args: -nobootcp -javabootclasspath ; -classpath C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\temp\scala\scalatest3\target\scala-2.12\classes;D:\Bin\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-library\jars\scala-library-2.12.0.jar

  last tree to typer: TypeTree(class ListBuffer)
       tree position: line 4 of D:\Temp\scala\scalatest3\src\main\scala\Main.scala
            tree tpe: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[() => Unit]
              symbol: final class ListBuffer in package mutable
   symbol definition: final class ListBuffer extends AbstractBuffer with Buffer with GenericTraversableTemplate with BufferLike with ReusableBuilder with SeqForwarder with Serializable (a ClassSymbol)
      symbol package: scala.collection.mutable
       symbol owners: class ListBuffer
           call site: constructor Main$delayedInit$body in class Main$delayedInit$body in package <empty>

== Source file context for tree position ==

     1   * Created by P20058 on 14.11.2016.
     2   */
     3 object Main extends App {
     4   println("Hello scalatest34")
     5 
     6 }

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$ClassBytecodeWriter.writeClass(BytecodeWriters.scala:120)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$ClassBytecodeWriter.writeClass$(BytecodeWriters.scala:118)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$$anon$4.writeClass(BytecodeWriters.scala:47)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenBCode$BCodePhase.sendToDisk$1(GenBCode.scala:408)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenBCode$BCodePhase.drainQ3(GenBCode.scala:427)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenBCode$BCodePhase.buildAndSendToDisk(GenBCode.scala:387)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenBCode$BCodePhase.run(GenBCode.scala:350)

    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1404)

    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1389)

    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1384)

    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1478)

    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:115)

    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:94)

    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:22)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:101)

    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:47)

    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)

    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:29)

    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:26)

    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:67)

    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:24)

    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

Rebuilding the project (*Build -> Rebuild Project*) works. But after some *make* iterations the error above reappears.
Any ideas what I miss?

Comment: How you exactly know this is an issue with ivy??

Comment: When I remove the option `-Dsbt.ivy.home=<new ivy home dir>` I get no build errors anymore. I think it's an issue of the IntellJ Scala plugin, because using *sbt* from the command line works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check libraries, in my case I was using 2 different version of the test libraries